# Angular2: NgModelChange called twice

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a angular2 component and I recognized that the ngModelChange event is triggered twice when I select another option in a select element.

I had a look to the generated code for the template of this component and I found out that there are 2 value accessors.

```
_View_SelectionPropertyComponent0.prototype._handle_change_7_1 = function($event) {
  var self = this;
  self.markPathToRootAsCheckOnce();
  self.debug(7,3,8);
  var pd_0 = (self._SelectControlValueAccessor_7_4.onChange($event.target.value) !== false); // First call
  self.debug(7,3,8);
  var pd_1 = (self._SelectControlValueAccessor_7_11.onChange($event.target.value) !== false); // Second call
  return ((true && pd_0) && pd_1);
};
```

This is the template of my component:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-xs-4 form-control-label">{{property.label}}</label>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <select class="form-control" [ngModel]="visual.appearance.get(property.name)" (change)="changeAppearance($event.target.value)" required>
            <option *ngFor="let p of property.options" [value]="p">{{p}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is this by design, because I am running the app in dev mode?

Comment: It does not happen any more with the newest version of the angular2. Probably it has been fixed.